# Phone number regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, phone-number

I need regular expression for phone number.

(from `0` to `9`) (total 10 digits)
Example: `"0123456789"`

Comment: View this Question. It has regex solutions for each and every type of phone number..


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a \d{10} would do the trick. But that is the lazy-man's way of validating as '0000000000' would pass a a valid entry.

But in case you know more about the domain, and the rules (I mean, if your phone number belongs to a specific country) and you want to make sure the number matches the local rules, then you can be a little bit more specif.

For example if all the numbers are starting with a leading zero, you can do this

0\d{9}

Or if the prefixes are well know... you can make an expression that allows phone numbers only starting with certain prefix(es).

(017|016|019|012)\d{7}

This will allow only those prefixes in the list, plus other 7 digits.

Answer (score 2):

its simple:

```
\d{10}
```

`\d` allows digits, and `{10}` indicates that the phone number must be exactly 10 digits long.

As you mentioned in the comment that you also want a regex for `012-345-6789`, `(\d{3}-){2}\d{4}` would do the work.
`(\d{3}-)` would validate the first 3 digits and a `-`

 `(\d{3}-){2}` would look for two occurrence of the above described group. So will validate: 012-345-
 And at last `\d{4}` will look for the last 4 digits

Comment: Ok this work. One more example if I want 012-345-6789, what regex should I use ?

Comment: you could go with this regex:

(\d{3}-){2}\d{4}

(\d{3}-) would validate the first 3 digits and a "-"
(\d{3}-){2} would look for two occurrence of the above described group. So will validate: 012-345-
And atlast \d{4} will look for 4 digits

Comment: i guess its not visible here. let me make an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern and match it:

```
\d{10}
```

`\d` : digits only.

`{n}`: numbers of occurrences.

You can refer this post for more info. [Regex for Phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)